# HTML Form Basics for PayPal Payments Standard custom fields

Tags: forms, email, paypal

I'm trying to put a PayPal form on my website but I would also like to put custom fields on it.

I mean, I would like to receive the details that maybe are different from the PayPal details.

Maybe someone does a payment but wants to use a PayPal account with a different email, so I would like to know both the emails.

I would like to create a form with these fields:

- First name
- Last name
- Personal email (not Paypal email)

and I want to be able to see these information when I receive the payment.

This is my form:

```
                <div id="paynow" class="contact_form_invoice_payment">

                    <div class="invoice_payment_title">Pay your invoice here</div>

                    <form method="post" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">

                        <input value="_xclick" name="cmd" type="hidden">
                        <input value="nessa@stressless.ie" name="business" type="hidden">
                        <input value="http://www.matrix-test.com/stressless/" name="return" type="hidden">
                        <input value="0" name="no_shipping" type="hidden">
                        <input value="1" name="no_note" type="hidden">
                        <input value="EUR" name="currency_code" type="hidden">
                        <input value="IE" name="lc" type="hidden">
                        <input value="PP-BuyNowBF" name="bn" type="hidden">
                        <input value="0" name="tax" type="hidden">
                        <input value="Online Payment" name="item_name" type="hidden">
                        <input value="OP" name="item_number" type="hidden">

                        <div class="first_name_invoice_payment">
                            First name (requiered) <br />
                            <input value="" name="first_name"> 
                        </div>

                        <div class="last_name_invoice_payment">     
                            Last name (requiered)<br />
                            <input value="" name="last_name"> 
                        </div>

                        <div class="email_invoice_payment">     
                            Email (requiered)<br />
                            <input value="" name="email"> 
                        </div>

                        <div class="first_name_invoice_payment">
                            Invoice Number (requiered)<br />
                            <input id="inv" value="" name="item_number">
                        </div>

                        <div class="last_name_invoice_payment">     
                            Amount - Euro Only (requiered)<br />
                            <input id="amt" value="" name="amount">
                        </div>

                        <div class="job_title_invoice_payment"> 
                            <input alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" name="submit" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" type="image" class="no-width image" style="width:auto !important; border:none; margin-top:20px;"> 
                            <img height="1" width="1" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" border="0" alt="">
                        </div>

                    </form>

                </div>
```

I tried to put these fields:

- name="first_name"
- name="last_name"
- name="email"

but I can't see them in the PayPal email and even in the PayPal backoffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the variables below to gather the information you are looking for:

on0 = CustomerName
os0 = "Enter First and Last Name"

on1 = CustomerEmail
os1 = "Enter Email Address"

Developer: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

Your updated code would look similar to this:

```
<input value="CustomerName" name="on0" type="hidden">
<input value="CustomerEmail" name="on1" type="hidden">

<div class="first_name_invoice_payment">
    First/Last name (requiered) <br />
    <input value="" name="os0"> 
</div>

<div class="email_invoice_payment">     
    Email (requiered)<br />
    <input value="" name="os1"> 
</div>
```

Comment: Should I see these parameters in the Paypal email?